# Battery as charge separating factory

Tags: charge, batteries

I like to think of electric battery as charge separating factory (similar to Van de Graaff generator). I took this idea from "Matter and Interactions" by Chabay and Sherwood. With this view of the battery I would like to understand why there is no potential difference between two different terminals of two batteries. Let us take + of battery A and - of battery B. Multimeter will show 0 voltage, but why? If we connect + and - of two different batteries, excess electrons from negative terminal will move towards lack of electrons on positive terminal, until potential equalizes. We will not be able to observe constant current, but for the short period of time (until everything equalizes) we will be able to see current. Is my understanding accurate?

P.S. there are some answers to similar questions on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, but cannot quite understand them and none of them offer model of the battery to support the statements.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, hypothetically, you should see a momentary current. However, without a complete current path to the other terminal of the battery, the discharge would roughly be the charge that builds up on the terminal itself, which would be miniscule for consumer electronics.

We can make some rough estimates of this by modeling a battery geometry as a parallel plate capacitor. Let us overall estimate such that the final capacitance is over-estimated. Take the areas (cathode/anode) to be 10 cm by 10 cm (high estimate for most consumer batteries) with a separation of 0.2 cm (low estimate) and a fill material of dielectric constant 1000 (high estimate for ionic liquids). This results in a capacitance of about 50 nF, which at 20 V is around 1 microCoulomb of charge on either side. Even with a meter response time of 0.1 s, this will produce a maximum averaged current of roughly 10 microAmps, which is still too small to detect with consumer multimeters.

Answer (score 1):

> Multimeter will show 0 voltage, but why?

I assume you're referring to a physical voltmeter which has a high but not infinite resistance, i.e., to measure a non-zero voltage requires a small but non-zero current through the voltmeter.

Since there is (as I understand the setup) no closed path for charge to flow - the two batteries are otherwise disconnected - there is no steady current through the voltmeter.

Comment: There is path for current to flow, but there is definitely no steady current

Comment: @user1700890, where is the *closed* path for charge to flow around?

Comment: I am thinking that - of battery A has excess of electrons and + of battery B lacks electrons, once you connect them by wire electron will flow from - of A to + of B creating current. am I missing something?

Comment: @user1700890, if that were to happen, then battery A would develop a bulk positive charge and battery B would have a bulk negative charge.  Very quickly, no additional charges could flow against this charge imbalance.  The system would be in equilibrium, and the voltmeter would show no potential difference.

Comment: @user1700890 As Alfred mentioned, a voltmeter actually measures the potential difference indirectly, by measuring the current flow through a large resistance. For this experiment, you don't want a big resistor dissipating any of the energy from the tiny transient current. Instead, you need a *very* sensitive [galvanometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanometer) with a fast response time.